# Grab bits from integer value in c

Tags: c, integer, int, complexity-theory, bit

I am given an integer named temp which is complex and consists of 3 temperatures high, low, and current. I need to grab bits 0-9 for the high, the middle 10-19 for the low, and 20-29 for the current temperature with 2 bits for errors. I am not sure how to go about it, but I know it involves the bitwise operators.

Comment: Do you know how bitwise operators work in C?

Answer (score 2):

```
int high = temp & (2^10-1);
int middle = (temp >> 10) & (2^10-1);
int low = (temp >> 20) & (2^10-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the bitwise operations, alternatively you could make a union containing your data type and a bit field with the specified pattern. Then all you have to do is to add your data type into the union and read out the bits from the bitfield data types.

Note bitfields may not be portable.

```
union helper
{
    struct
    {
          int low : 10;
          int current : 10;
          int high : 10;
          int error : 2;
     };
     int temp;
};
```

usage:

```
Helper h;
h.temp = input;
int low = h.low;
int current = h.current;
int high = h.high;
int error = h.error;
```

The plus about this solution is that its very readable, and that the compiler will automatically generate the bit operations to read each variable out.

Comment: Is this guaranteed to map to the bit you expect them to on all platforms, for example will switching from little endian to big endian break it?

Comment: Actually I think it will map just fine, just reversed, that is, if you flip the bitfield struct based on endianess you should be fine, also the datastructure should be tagged as packed to avoid padding. But I've already noted that portability can be an issue using this method, but in my eyes, it's worth it considering the readability and the relative low amount of issues I've had with it compared to unreadable bit operations.

Comment: Thats what I meant by not work, its not portable.

Comment: Well I agree, its a trade off between readability and portability.